# Terraform thinks Azure CDN Front Door route has been modified every time I run a plan

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I'm setting up an Azure CDN Front Door Profile using Terraform.

I'm having a problem with Terraform thinking that my routes have been changed every time I run a plan, even though they haven't been modified:

```
 # azurerm_cdn_frontdoor_route.main-fe-resources will be updated in-place
  ~ resource "azurerm_cdn_frontdoor_route" "main-fe-resources" {
      ~ cdn_frontdoor_origin_group_id = "/subscriptions/e68adbb2-af8e-4b01-a7e8-2bf599d6d818/resourcegroups/ci-redacted-frontdoor/providers/Microsoft.Cdn/profiles/ci-redacted-frontdoor/origingroups/main-fe" -> "/subscriptions/e68adbb2-af8e-4b01-a7e8-2bf599d6d818/resourceGroups/ci-redacted-frontdoor/providers/Microsoft.Cdn/profiles/ci-redacted-frontdoor/originGroups/main-fe"
        id                            = "/subscriptions/e68adbb2-af8e-4b01-a7e8-2bf599d6d818/resourceGroups/ci-redacted-frontdoor/providers/Microsoft.Cdn/profiles/ci-redacted-frontdoor/afdEndpoints/ci-main/routes/main-fe-resources"
        name                          = "main-fe-resources"
        # (8 unchanged attributes hidden)

        # (2 unchanged blocks hidden)
    }
```

The problems seems to be related to casing discrepancies between "resourceGroups" / "resourcegroups" and "originGroups" / "origingroups".

I've tried lowercasing the origin group ID in the Terraform script, but Terraform then complains that the ID doesn't contain the required string "originGroups".

I'm creating the routes like so:

```
resource "azurerm_cdn_frontdoor_route" "main-fe-resources" {
      name                          = "main-fe-resources"
      cdn_frontdoor_endpoint_id     = azurerm_cdn_frontdoor_endpoint.main.id
      cdn_frontdoor_origin_group_id = azurerm_cdn_frontdoor_origin_group.main-fe.id
      cdn_frontdoor_origin_ids      = []
      cdn_frontdoor_rule_set_ids    = []
      enabled                       = true
    
      forwarding_protocol    = "MatchRequest"
      https_redirect_enabled = true
      patterns_to_match      = ["/assets-2022/*", "/_next/*"]
      supported_protocols    = ["Http", "Https"]
    }
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you assigning the value in some way or you are referencing an attribute provided by another resource?

Comment: @MarkoE I'm referencing from another resource. I've added an example.

Comment: Is anything changing in the `azurerm_cdn_frontdoor_origin_group.main-fe` resource?

Comment: @MarkoE Nope, I can run apply over and over again without changing anything, but it never stabilizes.

Comment: Maybe there's a bug in the provider version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it does appear to be a bug in the provider. I originally created the routes manually, then added them to the Terraform state. I found that if I delete the routes and let Terraform recreate them then the problem goes away.

It's not an ideal solution, but at least the Terraform plans no longer detect changes when there aren't any.